# How to Get Shortest/Longest Posting Lists

Tags: c#, winforms, information-retrieval

I've written a `Class InvertedIndexTable {  }` here:

```
public interface IInvertedIndex
{
    int IndexSize(string path);
    void Load(string path);
}
class InvertedIndexTable : IInvertedIndex
{
     Dictionary<string, List<string>> index = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
     CreateMatrix r = new CreateMatrix(); // an object of another class contains stopwords{A,AN,...}
                                          // and also contains RemoveStopword() method
     public HashSet<string> DistincTerms = new HashSet<string>();
     public List<string> filesCollection = new List<string>();
     public int IndexSize(string pa)
     {
         Load(pa);
         return index.Count;
     }
     public void Load(string path)
      {
          string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Path.GetFullPath(path));
          foreach (string file in filePaths)
          {
              string contents = File.ReadAllText(file);
              contents = RemoveNonAlphaChars(contents);
              String[] tokensCollection = r.RemoveStopsWords(contents.ToUpper().Split(' '));
              foreach (string token in tokensCollection)
              {
                  if (!r.booleanOperator.Contains(token) && !DistincTerms.Contains(token))
                  {
                      DistincTerms.Add(token);
                  }
              }
          }
          Frequenty(filePaths);
      }
     public void Frequenty(string[] path1)
      {
        foreach (string d in DistincTerms)
        {
            foreach (string f in path1)
            {
                if (File.ReadAllText(f).Contains(d))
                {
                    filesCollection.Add(f);
                }

            }
            index.Add(d, filesCollection);
          }
      }
     private string RemoveNonAlphaChars(string content)
      {
          StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

          foreach (char c in content.ToCharArray())
          {
              if (char.IsLetter(c) || char.IsSeparator(c))
              {
                  sb.Append(c);
              }
          }
          return sb.ToString();
      }
     public  string GetSmallestPosting(string p)
      {
          List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
          if (index != null)
          {
              foreach( KeyValuePair<string,List<string>> i in index)
              {
                  string content= i.Value.ToString();
                  String[] itemsList = content.ToUpper().Split(' ');
                  numbers.Add(itemsList.Length); 
              }

              return numbers.Min().ToString();
          }
          return null;
      }
     public string GetLongestPosting(string p)
      {
          List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
          if (index != null)
          {
              foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<string>> i in index)
              {

                  string content = i.Value.ToString();
                  String[] itemsList = content.ToUpper().Split(' ');
                  numbers.Add(itemsList.Count());
              }
              return numbers.Max().ToString(); 
          }
          return null;
      }
}
```

I'm going to prepare button6 to show me Smallest and Longest posting lists of `Class InvertedIndexTable { }` also number of KeyValuePair of `Dictionary<string,List<string>> index`.
it works without any errors and exception,but the problem is : return value for DictionaryPairsNumbers is correct, but return values for MinSizePosting and MaxSizePosting are wrong, code always returns value "1" for both of them. why? what's the matter?

Code I wrote for button6 is right here :

```
    `  InvertedIndexTable i = new InvertedIndexTabe(); 
    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     MessageBox.Show("DictionaryPairsNumbers: " + i.IndexSize(textBox1.Text)+"\n\rMaxSizePosting: " + i.GetLongestPosting(textBox1.Text)+"\n\rMinSizePosting: "+ i.GetSmallestPosting(textBox1.Text));
    }
    `
```

please, let me know if there is any way that I achieve my expected result.
the result I need, is size of Shortest and longest `List<string>` in `Dictionary index` I thought I wrote right code for `GetSmallestPosting()` and `GetLongestPosting()` methods but it seems I was wrong, please tell me what's wrong with these two methods? why they return same values,always??? and why this value is "1",always???

by the way, `GetSmallestPosting()` finds shortest`List<string>`of `Dictionary<string,List<string>> index` and `GetLongestPosting()` finds the longest one.

thanks for your time.

Comment: it doesn't work because you can't get the minimum of `Collection<List<int>>` and that's what you have written. What exactly does the "smallest posting" means? Do you try to find the element who's `List<int>` has the less elements?

Comment: @ppetrov I've edited question completely, now it works but two of results aren't as I expected. it seems something is wrong with boths GetSmallestPosting() and GetLongestPosting but I don't know what it is. any help or explain?

Comment: @ppetrov, check out whole of question, please. I completely change the code

Comment: @Olivia: It seems that your initial question changed quite a bit from the beginning to now. I think it would be much easier for every one if you post a question and wait for an answer and then post a new question instead of changing your initial one.

Comment: @wonko79 I'm really sorry for that but I unable ask a new question, every time I click on Ask Question button I got this message 'Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account.', it seems site masters block me, I don't know how to fix it can't talk in chat rooms to anyone because I've not enough reputation for that. So I just change my old questions until  my broblem fixed.

Comment: @Olivia: Well there may is some reason to be blocked. To give you my last hint for your solution: use the methods in my answer to get the shortest/longest post, use Count on the list returned as result to get the length of this post. If you see better and simpler code which is actually working don't hesitate to throw away your own non-working attempt.

Comment: @wonko79 I posted an answer check it out please. it works who give me two int but that integers aren't the length of my posting lists, I mean Min should be 1 but it return 4 (but number of my .txt files are 4) that's because I'm not sure about result,it seems something is wrong with Frequenty() or maybe Load() method, I Checked but couldn't find out anything, any help?  please.

Comment: @Olivia: 1st your are continuously ignoring my answer. 2nd posting an answer and marking it as answer even though you know it's not wroking is some kind of meaningless to me.

Comment: @wonko79 I'm so sorry for that, I just wasn't sure but now I'm sure your answer is better than mine, can you help me find out why my answer returns 4 as min size of posting list? it must return 1 but it don't. why?

Comment: @ppetrov finally I've done I find the problem and I fixed it, I can't believe it. all of this is because of you you don't leave me on my own, you help me, explain to me. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Linq to do this.

Add two new methods to your InvertedIndex class.

**Min** goes through all key (X) value (List) pairs in your dictionary and returns the list with the smallest Count of items. **Max** does the exact opposite.

```
public List<T> GetSmallestPosting()
{
    if(_Index!=null)
       return  _Index.Values.First(v => v.Count == _Index.Min(kv => kv.Value.Count)).ToList();

    return null;
}

public List<T> GetLongestPosting()
{
    if(_Index!=null)
      return   _Index.Values.First(v => v.Count == _Index.Max(kv => kv.Value.Count)).ToList();

    return null;
}
```

Comment: can you explain more, please? what does it do exactly?

Comment: I tried but I just got an exception like this : " Null Reference Exception was unhandled"... how should I do it? and where? I try it in windows application mode of visual C#, when I click the button I must see the size of shortest and longest posting list in a messagebox as result. I get that Exception every time, what's wrong?

Comment: Oh as i just saw. My code supposes that Value (the List<T>) is never null.

Comment: Yes sorry for this mistake. Edited my answer accortingly.

Comment: the output is like this for me :'MinSizePosting: System.Collections.Generic.List'1[System.String]' but I need an int, or atleast a real List<string> ,not something like that so please tell me what's wrong?

Comment: So you are allways commenting below my answer and refering to the code you wrote?
BTW the solution provided in my answer returns a List<T>. If T is string then it returns a List<string>.

Answer (score 0):

for first I've changed `Frequenty() { }` method , it must be like this

```
public void Frequenty(string[] path1)
      {
         List<string> filesCollection = new List<string>();
         for (int i = 0; i < DistincTerms.Count(); i++ )
         {
             string d = DistincTerms.ElementAt(i);
             foreach (string f in path1)
             {
                 string c = File.ReadAllText(f);
                 c = r.RemoveNonAlphaChars(c);
                 String[] T = r.RemoveStopsWords(c.ToUpper().Split(' '));
                 foreach (string term in T)
                 {
                     if (term.Equals(d) && !filesCollection.Contains(f))
                     {
                         filesCollection.Add(f);
                     }
                 }

             }
             countor.Add(filesCollection.Count);
             index.Add(d, countor);
             filesCollection.Clear();
         }
```

now, I've turn both methods  GetSmallest/LongestPostingList :

```
 public string GetSmallestPosting(string p)
      {
          if (index != null)
          {
            return countor.Min().ToString();
          }
          return null;
      }
     public string GetLongestPosting(string p)
      {
          if (index != null)
          {
              return countor.Max().ToString();
          }
          return null;
      }
```

it works. I've tested it.

Comment: Instead of numbers.Add(count) write numbers.Add(pair.Vaue.Count) and delete unneccessary code. Or move int count = 0; 2 lines down.

Comment: @wonko79 I did it but it still returns same value, it must return 1 as min size of postings but it return 4

Comment: @wonko79 maybe something is wrong with Frequenty() method where Dictionary<string,List<string>> index is filled by some Key/Value Pair. I tried so much to find out what it is, but I couldn't find any wrong line in my code, so what's the matter?

Comment: @wonko79 Oh,I changed methods as you said but now code returns same value for both Min and Max posting lists and this value is 5 for both.

Comment: @wonko79 thank you so much you help me, explain to me and finally I got the answer.